# How to prioritise a SSL certificate when multiple certificates are provided for one domain?

Tags: ssl, nginx, webserver

I have generate two SSL certificates, one is RSA certificate and the other one is ECC certificate, for my domain `forum.example.com` and have implemented it in Nginx by using the following configuration:

```
    listen 443 ssl http2;  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name forum.example.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/forum.example.com.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate      /path/forum.example.com/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/forum.example.com/forum.example.key;
    ssl_certificate      /path/forum.example.com_ecc/fullchain.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key  /path/forum.example.com_ecc/forum.example.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam          /path/dhparams.pem;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;

    http2_idle_timeout 5m;

# Rest of the configuration
```

The idea behind this is to use ECC certificate whenever possible, and in the case where a client doesn't support ECC certificates, RSA certificate will be used. However, on my machine sometimes I see RSA certificate being used and sometimes ECC certificate being used. My guess is some round-robin method is being used to determine which certificate to use.

Is there a way to prioritise ECC over RSA, and if the client doesn't support ECC, the server will use RSA certificate?